# Resource for NPM's most downloaded this week/month

Tags: node.js, npm

Are there any sites that display this weeks/months most popular modules from Node Package Manger (NPM).

I know [www.npmjs.com](http://www.npmjs.com) have `packages people 'npm install' a lot` but that rarely changes. I also had a google for something like this, but turned up nothing.

I want something I can look through for new/trending packages for node.

Comment: There is a list [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xwlnv5xoecLqZHW2_H5g_plavVymijkqnCHRtNyOik/edit#gid=0) (from [the npm blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging)). Another list for most explicitly downloaded packages is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LyRwn6E8k7NM5bw2hJ7pWD7BWjgN_EskQ0ZMNphrffE/edit?usp=sharing) (from the same source). Both of these are until November 2014.

Comment: Quit somehow @2023 this service is lacking

Answer (score 1):

There is https://npm-stat.com/ which allows you to view the number of downloads per month/week/day of any individual package.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s most depended upon

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

request('https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended', function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) return false;
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $('h3 a').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).html() + ' - ' + $(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems that's no more valid.