# How can I list all npm packages with above X downloads?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking for some API that allows you to request "names of all npm packages with above X downloads". A curl command to do this would be great but if someone knows where I can get the data I could write my own script for it.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526255/resource-for-npms-most-downloaded-this-week-month) but nobody seems to have a nice answer for it. Most depended packages is easier if that also fits your need.

You can also use https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/download-counts.md to query for stats for individual packages, though this probably isn't efficient enough.